# What does a single . mean for a hostname lookup?

Tags: dns, hostname

Using uTorrent I noticed a peer with "." as a domain name. 
I thought it was strange so I looked up the IP using nslookup and similar online services.
I always get that the hostname is just a single dot.
What does this mean exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically just dummy data. The hostmaster for that network apparently doesn't want to properly configure [reverse DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup), either because of laziness, perceived security concerns, or some other reason. So instead of mapping the IP address to a reasonable hostname, he/she just picked `.`, though `foo.com`, `bar.com`, etc. would have worked as well.

Comment: It is worth noting that in regards to properly configured DNS records, a hostname of `.` represents the Internet root domain. More info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_name_server